# content flow problem with relative and fixed property

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hope all you are well
I face a little bit of tragic problem. I want to make simple login page with some attractive styling.

[image: this is the exact layout that i want to make]

But when I started coding outcome was different

[image: This is the outcome after coding]

My h1 element is not visible. It goes upper side of the message box and this is my problem. Help me sort out this
This is my html code

```css
/*Global part */
    @font-face {
        font-family: roboto;
        src: url('../files/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: pacifico;
        src: url('../files/fonts/Pacifico/Pacifico-Regular.ttf');
    }
    :root{
        --message-box-color:       #3D46E8;
        --message-color:           #ffffff;
        --font-color:              #000000;
        --input-field-color:       #E0E0E0;
        --input-field-focus-color: #EB5757;
    }
    
    
    /*Header Part */
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *:before,
    *:after{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: roboto;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    
    /*Message box*/
    .message-inner-box{
        position: fixed;
        top: -50px;
        left: -50px;
        height: 300px;
        width:  300px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: var(--message-box-color);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .title-container {
        margin-top: 50px;
        color: var(--message-color);
    }
    .title-container p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .heading {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .subheading {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_once('head.php'); ?>
        <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="message-container">
                <div class="message-inner-box">
                    <div class="title-container clearfix">
                        <p class="heading"> Hello, </p>
                        <p class="subheading"> Sign Up!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        <h1> Welcome </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no h1 element in your HTML, which h1 do you mean?

Comment: Sorry dear i forget to put h1 tag. Now I am edit my question. You can review

Comment: You have 6 opening `<div>` tags, but only 3 closing `</div>`. At the moment your h1 is inside `<div class="col-md-6">`

Answer (score 1):

Your h1 is there, it is just hidden behind the div with the class `message-inner-box`
you can see it by adding `position: absolute;` to your h1 styling,

```css
/*Global part */
    @font-face {
        font-family: roboto;
        src: url('../files/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: pacifico;
        src: url('../files/fonts/Pacifico/Pacifico-Regular.ttf');
    }
    :root{
        --message-box-color:       #3D46E8;
        --message-color:           #ffffff;
        --font-color:              #000000;
        --input-field-color:       #E0E0E0;
        --input-field-focus-color: #EB5757;
    }
    
    
    /*Header Part */
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *:before,
    *:after{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: roboto;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    
    /*Message box*/
    .message-inner-box{
        position: fixed;
        top: -50px;
        left: -50px;
        height: 300px;
        width:  300px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: var(--message-box-color);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .title-container {
        margin-top: 50px;
        color: var(--message-color);
    }
    .title-container p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .heading {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
    .subheading {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    h1 {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_once('head.php'); ?>
        <title>Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="message-container">
                <div class="message-inner-box">
                    <div class="title-container clearfix">
                        <p class="heading"> Hello, </p>
                        <p class="subheading"> Sign Up!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        <h1> Welcome </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanku so much dear. but can you explain me why this is happens

Comment: See Michel's comment for this.
Also, calling someone 'dear' on here sound really creepy, please stop it